# skydrive api windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, onedrive

Has anyone else had an issue with the SkyDrive API for Windows Phone 8?  I am upgrading my Windows Phone 7 code to Windows Phone 8.  When I click on the Login button (SkyDrive) I get the following screen:

[image]

This code (unchanged from WP7) used to work in VS2010.
Is anyone else having this issue?  Is there a newer version that I should use (current ver. v2.0.50727)?

Current XAML:

```
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="308,71,0,0" 
                 Name="signInButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" 
                 ClientId="[myID]" Scopes="wl.skydrive_update" 
                 TextType="SignIn" SessionChanged="btnSignin_SessionChanged"
                 Branding="Windows"/>
```

Login code-behind:

```
    private void btnSignin_SessionChanged(object sender, LiveConnectSessionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
        {
            client = new LiveConnectClient(e.Session);
            infoTextBlock.Text = "Signed in.";
            client.GetCompleted +=
                new EventHandler<LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs>(OnGetCompleted);
            client.GetAsync("me", null);
            for (var i = 0; i < this.ApplicationBar.Buttons.Count; i++)
            {
                var button = this.ApplicationBar.Buttons[i] as ApplicationBarIconButton;
                if (button != null)
                {
                    if (button.Text == "Upload")
                    {
                        button.IsEnabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            infoTextBlock.Text = "Not signed in.";
            client = null;
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE!**

I kept on trying and I was still getting this white screen.  However, I clicked on the magnifying glass and then hit the back arrow (it resumed) then tried to login again and it worked.  So is this just wonky or what?

Comment: That might be an emulator sluggishness issue if you are on emulator ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further review, I do believe that this is an emulator issue.  If I fiddle with it enough, eventually it works.

Answer (score 0):

I read that one cannot use the LiveSDK in the emulator, because you have no MS account in the emulator.

So try to use a physical device for debugging. That works for me.